# Родительский объект при использовании, this в методе объекта

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.

```
A={
  b:1,
  c:{
    z:0,
    f:function(){return this;} 
  }
}
```

При вызове `A.c.f()` ссылается на `c`, как можно сделать, чтобы `A.c.f()` ссылался на объект `A` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function createA() {
  var A = {
    b: 1,
    c: {
      A: null,
      z: 0,
      f: function() {
        return this.A;
      }
    }
  };
  A.c.A = A;
  return A;
}

var A = createA();
console.log(A.c.f());
```

```js
var A = {
  b: 1,
  c: {
    A: null,
    z: 0,
    f: function() {
      return A;
    }
  }
};

console.log(A.c.f());
```

Comment: А возможно ли добиться такого результата без явного присвоения?

Comment: @JarryRoxwell Посмотрите второй вариант. Не знаю, насколько прост Ваш случай, чтобы это Вам подошло.

Comment: в моем случае объект `A` - элемент массива, по этому взять его из глобального пространства не выйдет

Comment: @JarryRoxwell Объект не может получить (логически вычислить), какой другой объект содержит на него ссылку, без использования какой-то дополнительной информации.

Answer (score 2):

Это?

```js
let A={
  b:1,
  c:{
    z:0,
    f:function(){return this;} 
  }
};

console.info(A.c.f.call(A));
```

Comment: упростим: `console.log(A);`

Comment: Автору вроде нужно чтобы в `this` был родитель родителя, типа объект-дед.